# Migrate webservice to wcf

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have the following webservice code

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1, Name = "Service1")]
[ToolboxItem(false)]

public partial class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public SessionCredentials sessionHeader = new SessionCredentials();
    public class SessionCredentials{
        public Guid SessionID = Guid.Empty;
    }

    private bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            return (sessionHeader != null && sessionHeader.SessionID != Guid.Empty);
        }
    }

    [SoapDocumentMethod(Binding = "Service1")]
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("sessionHeader")]
    public System.Data.DataTable GetVisitList(Guid facilityID)
     {
        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            try
            {
                return test;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is working fine with no issues when calling this service. Now i migrated webservice to WCF with the below code

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1, Name = "Service1")]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public partial class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public SessionCredentials sessionHeader = new SessionCredentials();
    public class SessionCredentials{
        public Guid SessionID = Guid.Empty;
    }

    private bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            return (sessionHeader != null && sessionHeader.SessionID != Guid.Empty);
        }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public void SetCredentials(SessionCredentials session)
    {
        sessionHeader = session;
    }

    [SoapDocumentMethod(Binding = "Service1")]
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("sessionHeader")]
    [OperationContract]
    public System.Data.DataTable GetVisitList(Guid facilityID)
     {
        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            try
            {
                return test;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

also i update the web.config file with this

```
     <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <!--<service name="webservice" behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="webservice"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>-->
      <service name="webservice" behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="Service"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="returnFaults">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Somehow when i call GetVisitList in client i always get IsLoggedIn returns false even though i set sessionid before calling this method. Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the sessionHeader instance, you must set your service instance as  Single, or each call will gain its own instance

Use **InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single** in your service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single]
public partial class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

actually i just created a static variable and stored the sessionid and everytime i call another method that value still exists within the context.

Comment: Did this solve your problem or should this have been a comment on another post?

Comment: well it did not solved completely so trying wcfextras